# Traveling to the United States in 2022 without a Covid vaccine

Tags: usa, covid-19

As of 2022, is it required to have a Covid vaccination certificate to enter the United States? Does this depend on the state or mode of transportation? Are there exemptions for negative tests or prior infection?

Answer (score 2):

> As of 2022, is it required to have a Covid vaccination certificate to enter the United States?

Yes

> Are there exemptions for negative tests or prior infection?

There is an exemption for prior infection. Negative tests are required for everyone as well.

> If you recently recovered from COVID-19, you may instead travel with
> documentation of recovery from COVID-19 (i.e., your positive COVID-19
> viral test result on a sample taken no more than 90 days before the
> flight’s departure from a foreign country, and a letter from a
> licensed healthcare provider or a public health official stating that
> you were cleared to travel).

See:
https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/emergencies/covid-19-faqs-for-travel-to-the-us-information.html